# Json EOF validation in postmapping (@requestbody)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have written an endpoint as below:-

```
@PostMapping(value = "/payments", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
      consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE) 
public ResponseEntity<String> check(@RequestBody @Valid @Size Person person) 
{
System.out.println(person.getName());
return new ResponseEntity<String>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Class Person is

```
public class Person {

   private String name;
  private int age;
}
```

now when i use postman and submit below json

```
{
        "name": "akhil",
            "age": 21   

} {
        "name": "gaurav",
            "age": 21   

}
```

the code aptly prints `"akhil"`, no errors raised and next set containing gaurav is ignored.

whereas as per https://jsonlint.com/ above json should is rejected

Error:

> Parse error on line 5:
>   ...hil",    "age": 21} {    "name": "gaurav",
>   --------------------^
>   Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

EDIT
We need to reject the whole JSON message if more than 1 node is posted. I am trying to find out how to reject this 400 Bad request at RestController.

Comment: Welcome. json requires a single root node. Your endpoint only accepts 1 person, so you would need to call your endpoint twice, once for each `Person`. It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: We need to reject the whole JSON message if more than 1 node is posted. I am trying to find out how to reject this 400 Bad request at RestController. Can I use javax.constraints etc?